# Is this a valid mathematical proof?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, proof-verification, pi

When the circumference of a circle (c) and the perimeter of a square (8h) are equal, we call it a squared circle. Radius (r) is equal to one. (Fig. 1)

[image]

Next we simplify to the quarter squared circle which gives us our first triangle A. (Fig. 2)

[image]

Because a triangle has three sides it can be normalised in three ways, with exceptions. A normalised triangle is simply a triangle with one or more side-lengths equal to one. All sets of normalised triangles have the same angles.
See the example below, normalising the 345 triangle. (Fig. 3)

[image]

Notice above that the height of triangle 1 is the reciprocal of the hypotenuse of triangle 2, the base of triangle 1 is the reciprocal of the hypotenuse of triangle 3 and the base of triangle 2 is the reciprocal of the height of triangle 3. This is the case for all sets of normalised triangles.

We can use this rule to normalise triangle A. (Fig. 4)

[image]

When the perimeter of a square (8h) and the circumference of a circle (c) are equal, the ratio of the radius (r) to an eighth of the perimeter (h) will always be 4/Pi. (Fig. 5)

[image]

We can use this rule to create three nested versions of the quarter squared circle. (Fig. 6)

[image]

This gives us a second set of triangles D, E and F. (Fig. 7)

[image]

Notice that triangles D and A and triangles E and B are identical but triangles F and C are different. Next we interlock two quarter squared circles as shown below. (Fig. 8)

[image]

We then add a quarter circle with a radius (1+x). The arrows represent the tangents. (Fig. 9)

[image]

This gives us a third set of triangles J, K and L. (Fig. 10)

[image]

The set of triangles (A, B and C) and the set of triangles (J, K and L) should be identical, because both sets are normalised. If we compare the two sets we can extrapolate the following:

[image]

As shown below, it makes sense that y equals Pi/4, because we would expect the two marked points to be at the same height. The arrows represent the tangents. (Fig. 11)

[image]

If y equals Pi/4, it means that the triangle set (D, E and F) is also normalised. By comparing the three sets we can extrapolate the following:

[image]

If we do the calculations using the current value of Pi, the equations above fail. This points to the possibility that Pi is incorrect. So the question becomes, is there a value for Pi that satisfies all of the above equations?

Yes, here it is expressed as a fraction:

[image]

If we use the above value for Pi, we find that the three sets of triangles listed above, are in fact the same normalised set. (Fig. 12)

[image]

Because the circle and the square are both perfectly symmetrical, we should expect Pi to also have perfect symmetry. This symmetry can be expressed by the following equations:

[image]

So it seems, the angle (theta1) that squares the circle, perfect symmetry, occurs when its sine is equal to the reciprocal of its tangent.

Please be kind, this has taken over a year of my life so far.
Is this a valid proof?

Comment: Traditionally, "squaring a circle" refers to finding a square whose *area* equals that of a circle. You should make a note that you are using the phrase in a non-traditional sense. Also, since your discussion is quite lengthy, it would be helpful if you would state your goal at the beginning. I'm afraid it's hard for me to tell what exactly you are trying to prove.

Comment: *"This points to the possibility that Pi is incorrect. [So take $\pi := 4\sqrt{\sqrt{5/4}-\sqrt{1/4}}$.]"* ... um ... While you can define the symbol "$\pi$" to have any value you please, the value of the ratio of circumference to diameter in a circle is not in dispute, and it is *not* $4\sqrt{\sqrt{5/4}-\sqrt{1/4}}$. If your result is suggesting otherwise, then, no: *It is not a valid proof.*

Comment: @blue how do you explain the discrepancies between the three sets of normalised triangles then? They are all valid, do the calculations and check for yourself.

Comment: The figure is inaccurate (or rather, your interpretation of it is inaccurate), and this error propagates throughout the rest of your calculations all the way into your final result.

Comment: @FoldingCircles: Your comment about Figure 9 suggests that you believe the hypotenuse of triangle $K$ is tangent to the (original) quarter-circle. *It is not.* The fact that your subsequent calculation contradicts the value of the ratio of circumference to diameter proves the incorrectness of that tangency assumption, *not* the incorrectness of the value of that ratio.

Comment: On a positive note, you've shown that, to within a fraction of a percent, $$\pi \sqrt{\phi} \approx 4$$ where $\phi = 1.618\ldots$ is (as your avatar indicates that you know) the [Golden Ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio). That's kinda neat.

Comment: @Blue So, if this tangent does not happen like this (Fig 8 and Fig 9), for the perfectly symmetrical 'Squared Circle', when does it happen?

Comment: @FoldingCircles: There's no "if" about it; the claimed tangency simply *does not happen* in Figure 9. I have nothing else to say on this subject. Good luck to you.

Comment: "If we do the calculations using the current value of Pi, the equations above fail. This points to the possibility that Pi is incorrect. "  No.  That would  point to absolute and unquestionable certainty that your result is false.  To even consider you could be right and millenia of mathmatics is wrong assures you are a complete quack and this proof is useless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The triangle labeled K is not an alternative "normalization" of triangle J.
Triangle J is not similar to triangle K.

You constructed the hypotenuse of triangle K by connecting the center of one quarter-circle to the vertex of triangle J that lies on the other quarter-circle. There is nothing in that construction that guarantees that the
hypotenuse of K will be tangent to the first quarter-circle.

Indeed the hypotenuse is *not* tangent to the quarter-circle.
But because $4\sqrt{\sqrt{5/4}-\sqrt{1/4}}$ is between $\pi$ and $1.001\pi,$
the proportions of triangle K are "off" by less than $\frac1{10}\%,$
and it will be very difficult to see merely by looking at the figure
that the line and circle are not tangent.

It is not clear how you constructed triangle L.
If you did it by constructing a tangent to the quarter-circle
at the exact end of the quarter-circle (perpendicular to the horizontal
leg of triangle J)
and then extended the hypotenuse of triangle J until it met the
tangent line, triangle L will be a right triangle whose upper vertex
lies nearly (but not exactly) on the larger quarter-circle.
If you constructed L by extending the hypotenuse of J until it met the
larger quarter-circle, took that intersection point as one vertex, and took the lower end of the quarter-circle as another vertex, then L is not even a right triangle.

As with triangle K, however, it is very unlikely that you will be able to see the difference between the actual triangle L and the figure that your proof requires it to be, even with a very accurate drawing,
because the difference is so small.

I hope you did not really spend an entire year's worth of your time working on this and doing nothing else.

Comment: Because both the circle and square are perfectly symmetrical, we should expect the squared circle to have perfect symmetry.  Perfect symmetry happens when sin(theat1) is equal to the reciprocal of tan(theta1).

So, if this tangent does not happen like this (Fig 8 and Fig 9), for the perfectly symmetrical 'Squared Circle', when does it happen?

Theta1 for Pi(3.141) = 51.757518516021968193803782253708
Theta1 for Pi(3.144) = 51.82729237298775250653169866715

value for z using Pi(3.141) = 1.0034702381843646215280431622306
value for z using pi(3.144) = 1

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "perfect symmetry." (Certainly a square does not have as much symmetry as a circle; for example, a circle has mirror-image symmetry across any line through its center, but a square has mirror-image symmetry across only four lines.) You then take this concept (whatever it means) and conclude that $\sin(\theta_1) = 1/\tan(\theta_1)$ ... why? Apparently because it looks equal when you draw the figure.

Comment: You _will_ have $\sin(\theta) = 1/\tan(\theta)$ when $\sin(\theta) = \sqrt{\frac12(\sqrt5 - 1)}.$ You can then construct three right triangles using this value of $\theta$ as one angle, arranged exactly as shown in Figure 9, such that the vertices and intersections that look like they are on the quarter-circles are on the quarter circles, and the segments that look tangent to the quarter-circles are tangent. You can then construct a square whose side is twice the common leg of two of the triangles, and its perimeter will be $4\sqrt{2(\sqrt5 - 1)},$ which is just a _tiny bit more_ than $2\pi.$

Comment: David K > Thank you very much for your detailed reply's.